# Как лучше подсчитать кол-во объектов в разных списках, не учитываю дублирующие?

Tags: java, activity, android

Есть четыре вкладки, в каждой из которых я отображаю список из объектов. Объекты могут дублироваться в разных списках. Как лучше подсчитать кол-во объектов, не учитывая дублирующие? Объекты могут выглядеть так:

```
TestObject {
    int x;
    int y;
}

ArrayList<TestObject> list1;
ArrayList<TestObject> list2;
ArrayList<TestObject> list3;
ArrayList<TestObject> list4;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределите методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` и сложите свои объекты в `Set`:

```
Set<TestObject> unique = new HashSet<>();

unique.addAll(list1);
unique.addAll(list2);
unique.addAll(list3);
unique.addAll(list4);

unique.size()
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! немного позже опробую.

Comment: @iamtihonov Читайте лучше документацию, а не задавайте элементарные вопросы.

Comment: выходит объекты сначала используют для сравнения hashCode(), если они одинаковые, то выполняется метод equals(), если разные то и объекты считает разными, верно?

Comment: @iamtihonov да.